# Images in my browsers are blurry and of different size as in photoshop

Tags: image, browser, photoshop

I have a strange problem. When I save an image with photoshop ("save for web")
and put in to a website, the image is always bigger and not sharp.

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYGYt.jpg)

Here I compare the saved image, and the display in my browsers. 
(chrome, firefox, edge -  always the same)

I use Photoshop CS2 and Windows 10. Never mentioned this problem before
(normal screenshots, RGB Mode 8bit, safe as PNG. Should look exacty like
in Photoshop ...)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

solved it. windows 10 has a scaling of 25%
https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/4597/windows-10-feature-focus-display-scaling

and old Photoshop CS2 dont support it. so display is different....